# angular 2 ngIf and CSS transition/animation

Tags: css, angular, angular-animations

I want a div to slide in from the right in angular 2 using css.

```
  <div class="note" [ngClass]="{'transition':show}" *ngIf="show">
    <p> Notes</p>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="toggle(show)">Toggle</button>
```

I works fine if i only use [ngClass] to toggle class and utilise opacity.
But li don't want that element to be rendered from the beginning so I "hide" it with ngIf first, but then the transition wont't work.

```
.transition{
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1000ms ease-in-out,margin-left 500ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1000ms ease-in-out,margin-left 500ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 1000ms ease-in-out,margin-left 500ms ease-in-out ;
  -o-transition: opacity 1000ms ease-in-out,margin-left 500ms ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1000ms ease-in-out,margin-left 500ms ease-in-out;
  margin-left: 1500px;
  width: 200px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.transition{
  opacity: 100;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 240, accepted):

**update 4.1.0**

[**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/qS9Va2uxDb4KOpOQcNO5?p=preview)

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400-rc1-2017-02-24

**update 2.1.0**

[**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/uYlPTDzIJ1tPhwNF89dL?p=preview)

For more details see [**Animations at angular.io**](https://angular.io/guide/animations)

```ts
import { trigger, style, animate, transition } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  animations: [
    trigger(
      'enterAnimation', [
        transition(':enter', [
          style({transform: 'translateX(100%)', opacity: 0}),
          animate('500ms', style({transform: 'translateX(0)', opacity: 1}))
        ]),
        transition(':leave', [
          style({transform: 'translateX(0)', opacity: 1}),
          animate('500ms', style({transform: 'translateX(100%)', opacity: 0}))
        ])
      ]
    )
  ],
  template: `
    <button (click)="show = !show">toggle show ({{show}})</button>

    <div *ngIf="show" [@enterAnimation]>xxx</div>
  `
})
export class App {
  show:boolean = false;
}
```

**original**

`*ngIf` removes the element from the DOM when the expression becomes `false`. You can't have a transition on a non-existing element.

Use instead `hidden`:

```ts
<div class="note" [ngClass]="{'transition':show}" [hidden]="!show">
```

Comment: U mean `[hidden]` allow to let remains on DOM instead of removing from DOM ?

Comment: Yes, hidden only makes it invisible but the element still exists. `*ngIf` removes it entirely from the DOM.

Comment: so basically i can't have it removed from the DOM completely so save rendering time, and then animate it in? the [hidden] directive would work i guess the same way as display:hidden in css?

Comment: It's like `display:none`. There is no `display:hidden` AFAIK.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/yBr7pat89eKNvn4VPJkI
I've added the hidden directive but the transition doesnt work

Comment: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/4EkTkmqgG9HDiqDGEhAM?p=preview) I don't know if this is a good way. I'm by no means an CSS animation specialist.

Comment: display:none is not animatable so [hidden] is not useful in this case

Comment: @ÆndriDomi What do you suggest instead? `opacity`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer yes, opacity is Hardware accellerated so it will suit better.

Comment: Nevermind. opacity will not remove the element and will still cover the underneath elements, i suggest to use scale(0) wich will affect the UI such as display:none; but with a nice transition.
To answer the OP he can use the angular animations https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html
with transform:scale(0) at the void state

Comment: The solution is now deprecated.

Comment: @JoelHernandez can you please provide a link with more details?

Comment: The trigger, style, animate and transition items should now be included from @angular/animations . So import `{
    trigger,
    style,
    animate,
    transition
} from '@angular/animations';`

Comment: @JoelHernandez thanks a lot. I'm not using animations myself.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer animation is not showing on safari devices. How can I use -webkit-transform in here?

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot sorry, but I don't know about Safari.

Comment: Import is `from '@angular/core';` within Angular5.

Comment: Sorry, had to do `npm i @angular/animations@5`. Feel free to rollback.

Comment: @GaryKlasen thanks again for the feedback. I haven't used animations with Angular myself except for this answer :D I remember there was a change, but I think it was moving it from core to its own animations module.

Comment: so why is that transition is not working.  For this specific task, I had css class that increase height set to 90px from class that set height to 0px.   I used  [class]="toggleBetweenClass()" to return the class name when a variable is set true and false on click.  Why does transition in css not apply?  (a work around using css).

Comment: I suggest to create a new question with a stackblitz example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @lampshade if you add the CSS to index.html instead of a component, this should still work. Alternatively you should also be able to accomplish this with a reusable directive.

Answer (score 185):

According to the latest [angular 2 documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html) **you can animate "Entering and Leaving" elements** (like in angular 1).

Example of simple fade animation:

In relevant @Component add:

```
animations: [
  trigger('fadeInOut', [
    transition(':enter', [   // :enter is alias to 'void => *'
      style({opacity:0}),
      animate(500, style({opacity:1})) 
    ]),
    transition(':leave', [   // :leave is alias to '* => void'
      animate(500, style({opacity:0})) 
    ])
  ])
]
```

Do not forget to add imports

```
import {style, state, animate, transition, trigger} from '@angular/animations';
```

The relevant component's html's element should look like:

```
<div *ngIf="toggle" [@fadeInOut]>element</div>
```

I built example of *slide and fade animation* [**here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/2FaCZeruyu6EQn5t3GWY?p=preview).

**Explanation** on 'void' and '*':

- `void` is the state when `ngIf` is set to false (it applies when the
  element is not attached to a view).
- `*` - There can be many animation states (read more in docs). The `*` state takes precedence over all of them as a "wildcard" (in my example this is the state when `ngIf` is set to `true`).

**Notice** (taken from angular docs):

**Extra** declare inside the app module,
`import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';`

> Angular animations are built on top of the standard Web Animations API
>   and run natively on browsers that support it. For other browsers, a
>   polyfill is required. Grab web-animations.min.js from GitHub and add
>   it to your page.

Comment: Need to import the BrowserAnimationsModule to use angular animations. If I'm not wrong, the animation module was found in the core module of angular 2 before being moved to its own module, hence why you find many plunker examples without the import. Here's an updated plnkr with the import: [Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/2FaCZeruyu6EQn5t3GWY?p=preview)

Comment: When using such approach the `leave` animation is not taking place , because component is removed from the DOM by `*ngIf` prior to that.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, It actually gives the solution to those who want to use ngIf and not other workarounds.

Answer (score 21):

```
    trigger('slideIn', [
      state('*', style({ 'overflow-y': 'hidden' })),
      state('void', style({ 'overflow-y': 'hidden' })),
      transition('* => void', [
        style({ height: '*' }),
        animate(250, style({ height: 0 }))
      ]),
      transition('void => *', [
        style({ height: '0' }),
        animate(250, style({ height: '*' }))
      ])
    ])
```

Answer (score 18):

CSS only solution for modern browsers

```
@keyframes slidein {
    0%   {margin-left:1500px;}
    100% {margin-left:0px;}
}
.note {
    animation-name: slidein;
    animation-duration: .9s;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Good alternative for **enter** CSS-only transition. Used this as a temporal solution for migrating from `ng-enter` class usage.

Answer (score 5):

One way is to use a setter for the ngIf property and set the state as part of updating the value.

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ebqdz5)

**fade.component.ts**

```
 import {
    animate,
    AnimationEvent,
    state,
    style,
    transition,
    trigger
  } from '@angular/animations';
  import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

  export type FadeState = 'visible' | 'hidden';

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-fade',
    templateUrl: './fade.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./fade.component.scss'],
    animations: [
      trigger('state', [
        state(
          'visible',
          style({
            opacity: '1'
          })
        ),
        state(
          'hidden',
          style({
            opacity: '0'
          })
        ),
        transition('* => visible', [animate('500ms ease-out')]),
        transition('visible => hidden', [animate('500ms ease-out')])
      ])
    ],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
  })
  export class FadeComponent {
    state: FadeState;
    // tslint:disable-next-line: variable-name
    private _show: boolean;
    get show() {
      return this._show;
    }
    @Input()
    set show(value: boolean) {
      if (value) {
        this._show = value;
        this.state = 'visible';
      } else {
        this.state = 'hidden';
      }
    }

    animationDone(event: AnimationEvent) {
      if (event.fromState === 'visible' && event.toState === 'hidden') {
        this._show = false;
      }
    }
  }
```

**fade.component.html**

```
 <div
    *ngIf="show"
    class="fade"
    [@state]="state"
    (@state.done)="animationDone($event)"
  >
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary">test</button>
  </div>
```

**example.component.css**

```
:host {
  display: block;
}
.fade {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Am using angular 5 and for an ngif to work for me that is in a ngfor, I had to use animateChild and in the user-detail component I used the *ngIf="user.expanded" to show hide user and it worked for entering a leaving

```
 <div *ngFor="let user of users" @flyInParent>
  <ly-user-detail [user]= "user" @flyIn></user-detail>
</div>

//the animation file


export const FLIP_TRANSITION = [ 
trigger('flyInParent', [
    transition(':enter, :leave', [
      query('@*', animateChild())
    ])
  ]),
  trigger('flyIn', [
    state('void', style({width: '100%', height: '100%'})),
    state('*', style({width: '100%', height: '100%'})),
    transition(':enter', [
      style({
        transform: 'translateY(100%)',
        position: 'fixed'
      }),
      animate('0.5s cubic-bezier(0.35, 0, 0.25, 1)', style({transform: 'translateY(0%)'}))
    ]),
    transition(':leave', [
      style({
        transform: 'translateY(0%)',
        position: 'fixed'
      }),
      animate('0.5s cubic-bezier(0.35, 0, 0.25, 1)', style({transform: 'translateY(100%)'}))
    ])
  ])
];
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I declared the animation on the wrong component by mistake.

**app.component.html**

```
  <app-order-details *ngIf="orderDetails" [@fadeInOut] [orderDetails]="orderDetails">
  </app-order-details>
```

The animation needs to be declared on the component where the element is used in (`appComponent.ts`). I was declaring the animation on `OrderDetailsComponent.ts` instead.

Hopefully it will help someone making the same mistake