# angular 6 animation *ngIf, transition not work

Tags: angular, animation, transition

The project presents two variants of animation.

*Animation Option 1, trigger('animationOption1')*
Works without complaints.

*Animation Option 2, trigger('animationOption2')*
**transition doesn't work here.**

[Online check this project in StackBlitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/github/MyTempGitForCommunity/angular-6-animation-transition)

app.component.html

```
<h1>Animation Option 1</h1>
<div (click)="changeDivState()"
     [@animationOption1]="clickedDivState"
>Click Me
</div>

<h1>Animation Option 2</h1>
<button (click)="toggleMenu()">Click Me</button>
<ul *ngIf="isMenuOpen"
    [@animationOption2]="isMenuOpen ? 'open': 'close'"
>
  <li>Menu Item 1</li>
  <li>Menu Item 2</li>
  <li>Menu Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('animationOption1', [
      state('start', style({
        backgroundColor: 'yellow',
        width: '150px',
        height: '150px'
      })),
      state('end', style({
        backgroundColor: 'green',
        width: '300px',
        height: '300px'
      })),
      transition('start => end', animate(1500)),
      transition('end => start', animate('800ms 0.5s ease-out'))
    ]),
    trigger('animationOption2', [
      state('close', style({
        opacity: 0,
        backgroundColor: 'yellow'
      })),
      state('open', style({
        opacity: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'green'
      })),
      transition('close <=> open', animate(3000)),
    ])
  ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  isMenuOpen = false;

  clickedDivState = 'start';

  changeDivState() {
    this.clickedDivState = 'end';
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.clickedDivState = 'start';
    }, 3000);
  }

  toggleMenu(): void {
    this.isMenuOpen = !this.isMenuOpen;
  }
}
```

Googling did not lead to a solution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To get this to work you will need to remove the `*ngIf="isMenuOpen"` on the `<ul>`. Angular is unable to calculate the transition between the `closed`/`open` states as the element simply does not exist when `isMenuOpen` is `false`.

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-gsrna1) showing the animation in action with `*ngIf` removed.

Alternatively you can utilize [entering/leaving](https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers#animating-entering-and-leaving-a-view) states to use in conjunction with `*ngIf`. It would look like this:

```
trigger('animationOption2', [      
  transition(':enter', [
    style({ backgroundColor: 'yellow' }),
    animate(300)
  ]),
  transition(':leave', [
    animate(300, style({ backgroundColor: 'yellow' }))
  ]),
  state('*', style({ backgroundColor: 'green' })),
])
```

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-gsrna1-yxgpmf) in action.

Comment: Yes, thank you, Alexander! However, the list remains in the document flow when you solve it, but it is easily corrected by adding the 'display' property with the corresponding values for the States.

Comment: If you need to remove it from the document flow, you can actually `:enter` and `:leave` transitions. You can then use `*ngIf`. Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36417931/angular-2-ngif-and-css-transition-animation)

Comment: You can also use the `:enter` and `:leave` transitions

Comment: Damn it, now understandable for what need these [":enter" and ":leave"](https://angular.io/api/animations/transition#using-enter-and-leave), thanks

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I have used mentioned solution but time i am passing isn't working. Its just hide/show immediately like *ngIf default. Any idea what can be wrong?

Comment: @AkashJain You should create a new question to get the best possible support for your issue.