# how can I make a transition effect to opacity 0 with ending in display: none?

Tags: css, angular

With this code I am simulating a `sidemenu`, so if I click on the `button` an `overlay` that contains the `sidemenu` opens and the `sidemenu` moves to the right. if I `click` `outside`, the `overlay` disappears and the menu returns to its initial position.

.html

```
<div class="menuside_container" (click)="fn_hideSideMenu()" [ngClass]="showSideMenuContainer?showSideMenuContainer:''">
  <div class="menuside" [ngClass]="{showmenu:showMenu, hidemenu:!showMenu}">
    

    <a  class="menu-item d-block" style="height:46px">
      option 1
    </a>
    <a  class="menu-item d-block" style="height:46px">
      option 2
    </a>
    <a  class="menu-item d-block" style="height:46px">
      option 3
    </a>
    <hr class="m-0">
  </div>

</div>
<button (click)="fn_showSideMenu()">show menu</button>
```

.ts

```
showMenu: boolean = false;
showSideMenuContainer: any = "d-none";

 fn_showSideMenu() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.showMenu = true;
  });
  this.showSideMenuContainer = "d-block";
}
fn_hideSideMenu() {
  this.showMenu = false;
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.showSideMenuContainer = "d-none";
  }, 400);
}


.menuside {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 304px;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  height: 100%;
}

.menuside_container {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 999;
}
```

.css

```
.showmenu {
  left: 0px;
}

.hidemenu {
  left: -500px;
}
```

this code works, but i think i am complicating things a lot, maybe i don't need to put code in my .ts, but my idea is that, i just want to know if i can solve the same effect i have from `css` and / or `html` code in `angular`

[image]

I would like when I click on the `button` to show the `overlay` and then the transition from the `sidemenu` to the right, and when I click once the overlay is displayed, it will show the transition from my `sidemenu` to its starting point.

Regarding the question title, I put it because if I put a `display: none` at the beginning to `.menuside_container`, the transition of the `sidemenu` is not shown

thank you.
I'm just looking for an optimal solution to my problem

this is my live code (see `app/app.component.`html/ts/css):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-bootstrap-wa3xto?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

**Note:**

I basically want to do what is shown in the gif, but in a more optimal way. I use `setTimeouts` to achieve it. but as the question says, I am interested in how I can make a transition of an element with the opacity effect from 1 to 0 but have the property `display: none` at the end. why? I want to hide an element completely, but with `opacity: 0` it will still occupy the `space` even though it is not visible

Comment: hey @yavg, could you please clarify your problem or at least further explain it ??

Comment: and i think you should use angular animations, instead of CSS that will be more efficient.

Comment: @OwaisAhmedKhan friend, I basically want to do what is shown in the gif, but in a more optimal way. I use `settimeouts` to achieve it. but as the question says, I am interested in how I can make a transition of an element with the opacity effect from 1 to 0 but have the property `display: none` at the end. why? I want to hide an element completely, but with `opacity: 0` it will still occupy the space even though it is not visible

Comment: I think, a better approch will be to replace `setTimeout` by `animationend` event on your menu

Comment: @CedricCholley who can do it?

Comment: @yavg What do you mean ? Who can replace `setTimeout` by `animationend` ? What I've meant is instead of timing a `setTimeout` with the same delay as the animation duration, use an `addEventListener('animationend', …)` on your menu

Comment: @yavg, why not use Angular animations? See my answer and check the docs in https://angular.io/guide/animations

Comment: @yavg did you get a chance to look at the answer provided? Did it work?

Answer (score 3):

You can use very simple html and CSS based menu with animation. Take a look at this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-bootstrap-xiqz9e) forked from yours.

For example:

```js
function closeMenu() {
  document.querySelector(".menuside_container").classList.add("hidemenu");
  document.querySelector(".menuside_container").classList.remove("showmenu");
}

function showMenu() {
  document.querySelector(".menuside_container").classList.remove("hidemenu");
  document.querySelector(".menuside_container").classList.add("showmenu");
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: blue;
}

@keyframes menuOpen {
  from {
    opacity: 0.5;
    transform: translateX(-500px);
    display: none;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translatX(0);
    display: block;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
}

@keyframes menuClose {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
    display: block;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0.5;
    transform: translateX(-500px);
    display: none;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}

.menuside {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 304px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}

.menuside_container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
}

.showmenu,
.hidemenu {
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.showmenu {
  animation-name: menuOpen;
}

.hidemenu {
  animation-name: menuClose;
}

.d-block {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menuside_container hidemenu" onclick="closeMenu()">
  <div class="menuside">
    <a class="menu-item d-block" style="height:46px">
      option 1
    </a>
    <a class="menu-item d-block" style="height:46px">
      option 2
    </a>
    <a class="menu-item d-block" style="height:46px">
      option 3
    </a>
    <hr class="m-0">
  </div>

</div>
<button onclick="showMenu()">show menu</button>
```

Comment: of course you can use jQuery with Angular, but you should avoid to do it

Comment: @Eliseo it doesn't need jQuery. In my plain HTML example I just used it to add and remove class. Updated my sample to just contain vanilla JS. Also, if you look at stackblitz code, it doesn't have jQuery as dependency.

Comment: true, sorry, I see `document.querySelector` and make me crazy :) (anyway, I think that it's not "Angular way", -in Angular way, you can use ViewChildren-)

Comment: @Eliseo sure by I am not using angular in html css only code. Did you even looked at stablitz attached?

Comment: Yes!, `[ngClass]` is "Angular way", I like your solution in stackblitz :) -sorry, I only saw the answer-

Comment: No worries, I bet you did not had coffee :)

Answer (score 1):

You're actually achieving exactly what you want to do already. If you check the console, you will see that `.menuside_container` has `display:none` before the animation runs, and is restored to this after the menu closes. This is because you are applying the `d-none` class to it which applies the following declaration: `display: none!important;`

There are other things you could do to improve your code. As others have pointed out, Angular does have its own animation system and you might want to look into that. Also, instead of doing the animation using the `left` property, you could use the `translateX()` function instead, which is considered to be much more performant. This is achieved by making the following change:

```
.showmenu {
  /* left: 0px; */
  transform: translateX(0)
}

.hidemenu {
  /* left: -500px; */
  transform: translateX(-500px)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you not only want to display none, else remove from DOM, you can achieve using Angular animations. Define in your component

```
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"],
  animations: [
    trigger("menuOpenClose", [
      transition(":enter", [
        style({ left: "-300px"}), //state initial
        animate("100ms", style({ left: 0 }))  //animate to a final state
        ]),
      transition(":leave", [animate("100ms", style({ left: "-300px" }))])
    ])
  ]
})
```

So you simply declare a variable

```
open=false;
```

And a html like

```
<div @menuOpenClose class="menuside" *ngIf="open">
  <button (click)="open=false">close</button>
</div>
<button (click)="open=true">open</button>
```

See the [very ugly stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sd7vwr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**Update** improve the "menu"

You declare two auxiliar variables

```
submenuOpen=false;
openFinished=false;
```

And a .class like

```
.fade {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  z-index: 999;
}
```

See the .html -where you use open=true and (@menuOpenClose.done)-

```
<!--
  if you want close when click in any place of "#menu" add
     (click)="open=false"
  if you want close ONLY y you click in "menu" (but not if click in a button inside "menu") e.g. you has a "submenu"
     (click)="$event.target==menu && open=false"
-->

<div #menu @menuOpenClose (@menuOpenClose.done)="openFinished=!openFinished" 
         class="menuside" *ngIf="open"
         (click)="$event.target==menu && open=false">
    <button (click)="open=false">close</button>
    <div>
        <button (click)="submenuOpen=!submenuOpen" >menu</button>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="submenuOpen" (click)="open=false">
        <hr />
        <button (click)="doIt('I\'m menu 1')">menu-1</button>
        <button (click)="doIt('I\'m menu 2')">menu-2</button>
    </div>
</div>
<button (click)="open=true">open</button>
<div class="fade" *ngIf="openFinished" (click)="open=false"></div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eius
```

Comment: I think this answer is simple and solves the problem in the most effective way

Answer (score 0):

if you want `display: none` to prevent click to the element you can use `pointer-events: none;`.

You can also have a single class to show the menu and assume that the normal state is hidden.

So my suggestion is

```css
.menuside {
  [...]
  transition: transform 0.3s linear;
  [...]
  transform: translateX(-500px)
}

.menuside_container {
  [...]
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
  opacity: 0;
}

.menuside.showmenu {
  transform: translateX(0)
}

.menuside_container.showmenu {
  pointer-events: auto;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

your functions in the `.ts` just need to set the `showMenu` property

```
 fn_showSideMenu() {
   this.showMenu = true;
 }
 fn_hideSideMenu() {
   this.showMenu = false;
 }
```

and the `html` is:

```html
<div class="menuside_container" (click)="fn_hideSideMenu()" [ngClass]="{showmenu:showMenu}">
  <div class="menuside" [ngClass]="{showmenu:showMenu}">
    <a  class="menu-item d-block" style="height:46px">
      option 1
    </a>
    <a  class="menu-item d-block" style="height:46px">
      option 2
    </a>
    <a  class="menu-item d-block" style="height:46px">
      option 3
    </a>
    <hr class="m-0">
  </div>

</div>
<button (click)="fn_showSideMenu()">show menu</button>
```

You can look at a fork I made at your Stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-bootstrap-rcwejo?file=app/app.component.css

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by using `Javascript` [`Element.animate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate) or by creating the same animation using `CSS` (you would need two helper classes e.g. *closed, open* for that). Use `translateX()` instead of `left` for your animation.

You will be needed to use the [`animationend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event) event in order to apply `display: none` only when after the animation has ended.

Some elements are not needed for this effect. For example there is no need for `.menuside_container` and only one simple helper class was used.

Please check the logic of the following example:

```js
const menuside = document.querySelector('.menuside');

menuside.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
  menuside.style.display = 'none';

});

menuside.addEventListener('click', () => {
  menuside.animate([
    // keyframes
    {
      transform: 'translateX(0)',
      opacity: '1'
    },
    {
      transform: 'translateX(-304px)',
      opacity: '0'
    }
  ], {
    // timing options
    duration: 1000,
    fill: 'forwards',
    direction: 'normal',
    iterations: 1
  });
  menuside.classList.add('closed');
});

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (menuside.classList.contains('closed')) {
    menuside.style.display = 'block';
    menuside.animate([
      // keyframes
      {
        transform: 'translateX(0)',
        opacity: '1'
      },
      {
        transform: 'translateX(-304px)',
        opacity: '0'
      }
    ], {
      // timing options
      duration: 1000,
      fill: 'forwards',
      direction: 'reverse',
      iterations: 1
    });
    menuside.classList.remove('closed');
  }
});
```

```css
.menuside {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 304px;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 3rem;
  right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="menuside">
  <a class="menu-item d-block" style="height:46px">
      option 1
    </a>
  <a class="menu-item d-block" style="height:46px">
      option 2
    </a>
  <a class="menu-item d-block" style="height:46px">
      option 3
    </a>
  <hr class="m-0">
</div>
<button>show menu</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine i got the same thing as shown in the gif of yours without using setTimeout but as you can see that despite of using display property equal to none in @keyframes it won't show any changes because display property is not animatable
.To check the full list of animatable properties visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties

```js
var overlay=document.getElementById('overlay');
    var menuside=document.getElementById('menuside');
    
    function show_menu(){
overlay.style.display="block";
    overlay.style.animation="show_overlay 0.6s 1";
    overlay.style.animationFillMode="forwards";
    menuside.style.animation="show_menu_pane 0.6s 1";
    menuside.style.animationFillMode="forwards";

}
    
    function hide_menu(){
    menuside.style.animation="hide_menu_pane 0.6s 1";
    menuside.style.animationFillMode="forwards";
    overlay.style.animation="hide_overlay 0.6s 0.3s 1";
    overlay.style.animationFillMode="forwards";
    
    }
```

```css
*{
            
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            font-family: 'Arial';
        }
        body{
            background-color: blue;
        }
    .menuside {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 304px;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 900;
  transform: translateX(-304px);
 
}
.menuside li{
    padding: 10px;
}
.menuside li a{
  text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    color:#707070;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
.menuside li a:hover{
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.menuside_container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  z-index:-1;
 
}
.overlay{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index:8;
    transition:0.6s;
    opacity: 1;
}

@keyframes hide_overlay
{
    from
    {
    opacity: 1; 
    display: block;
    z-index: 8;
    }
    to
    {
opacity: 0;
display: none;
z-index: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes show_overlay
{
    from
    {
    opacity: 0; 
    z-index: 0;
    }
    to
    {
opacity: 1;
    z-index: 8;
    }
}
@keyframes show_menu_pane
{
    from
    {
    transform: translateX(-304px);
    }
    to
    {
    transform: translateX(0px);
    }
}
@keyframes hide_menu_pane
{
    from
    {
    transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    to
    {
    transform: translateX(-304px);
    }
}


button{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 10px;
    border:1px solid black;
    font-size: 18px;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="menuside_container" >
  <div class="overlay" id="overlay" onclick="hide_menu()"></div>
  <div class="menuside" id="menuside">
    
    <ul>
    <li>
    <a href="#/" class="menu-item d-block" style="height:46px">
      option 1
    </a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#/" class="menu-item d-block" style="height:46px">
      option 2
    </a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#/" class="menu-item d-block" style="height:46px">
      option 3
    </a>
    </li>
    <hr class="m-0">
    </ul>
  </div>
<button onclick="show_menu()">Show Menu</button>
</div>
```

#### 2. Another alternative of display:none would be making width and height equal to zero ,the result will be same as the gif but opacity transition won't work.

```js
var overlay=document.getElementById('overlay');
    var menuside=document.getElementById('menuside');
    
    function show_menu(){
overlay.style.display="block";
    overlay.style.animation="show_overlay 0s 1";    
    overlay.style.animationFillMode="forwards";
    menuside.style.animation="show_menu_pane 0.6s 1";
    menuside.style.animationFillMode="forwards";
    
}

    function hide_menu(){
    menuside.style.animation="hide_menu_pane 0.6s 1";
    menuside.style.animationFillMode="forwards";
    overlay.style.animation="hide_overlay 0s 0.6s 1";
    overlay.style.animationFillMode="forwards";

    }
```

```css
    *{
            
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            font-family: 'Arial';
        }
        body{
            background-color: blue;
        }
    .menuside {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 304px;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 900;
  transform: translateX(-304px);
 
}
.menuside li{
    padding: 10px;
}
.menuside li a{
    font-size: 18px;
    color:#707070;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
.menuside li a:hover{
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.menuside_container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 304px;
  height: 100%;
 
}
.overlay
{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index:14;
    transition:0.6s;
}

@keyframes hide_overlay{
    from{
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
    
}
    to{
width:0vw;
height:0vh; 
    }
}
@keyframes show_overlay{
    from{
width:0vw;
height:0vh;
}
    to{
width:100vw;
height:100vh;   
    }
}
@keyframes show_menu_pane
{
    from
    {
    transform: translateX(-304px);
    }
    to
    {
    transform: translateX(0px);
    }
}
@keyframes hide_menu_pane
{
    from
    {
    transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    to
    {
    transform: translateX(-304px);
    }
}


button{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 13;
    padding: 10px;
    border:1px solid black;
    font-size: 18px;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
  <div class="overlay" id="overlay" onclick="hide_menu()"></div>  

<div class="menuside_container" >
  
  <div class="menuside" id="menuside">
    <ul>
    <li>
    <a href="#/" class="menu-item d-block" style="height:46px">
      option 1
    </a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#/" class="menu-item d-block" style="height:46px">
      option 2
    </a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#/" class="menu-item d-block" style="height:46px">
      option 3
    </a>
    </li>
    <hr class="m-0">
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="show_menu()" id="button">Show Menu</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

`display:none` isn't affected by transition speeds, and therefore **cannot** be done by pure, vanilla CSS.

You can:

1. Use a workaround. (For example, you can use `visibility:hidden;`, or `width:0;height:0;overflow:hidden;margin:0;`, which *are* affected by transition-delay.

OR

2. You can use javascript, like you've done in your example,

OR

3. Angular itself actually has built-in animation support, that you can set up to trigger whenever an `*ngIf` triggers. For example, here: [angular 2 ngIf and CSS transition/animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36417931/angular-2-ngif-and-css-transition-animation)

Answer (score -2):

take the code from this repo. the thing you want is implemented in responsive mode.

Code: https://github.com/muhammadawaisshaikh/gamelist-ui-test/tree/master/header 
**Preview Live:** https://muhammadawaisshaikh.github.io/gamelist-ui-test/header/

Comment: thanks, but i don't see how to do what i need. a transition ending in `display: none`

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. Instead, include the solution in the body of your answer.

Comment: you have to convert display property to visibility that will work fine in your situation.

Answer (score -2):

Actually you will have to use translateX to achieve a smooth 60fps animation.

You can read the theory behind this in this article (https://medium.com/outsystems-experts/how-to-achieve-60-fps-animations-with-css3-db7b98610108) or just grab the code at end of the article

Comment: thanks, but i don't see how to do what i need. a transition ending in `display: none`

Comment: the issue that you are facing is that the toggling of the display property from block to none can not be animated. the article that i shared explains it. if you have a look at the code you will see that it achieves the same result but with a more efficient and smooth way. if you still need to end with display: none then i am sorry but i can not help you.