# css transition on opacity angular

Tags: css, angular, css-transitions

I'm trying to create a small **snackbar** in angular which takes as input an array and show each notification for a few seconds before popping it from the stack and showing the next.

i'd like to have an **opacity transition in and out** between those notification.

**Transition property doesn't seems to work**

Here's the [stackblitz link](https://codesandbox.io/s/neobrutal-snackbar-sud6ec?file=/src/app/snackbar/snackbar.component.ts)

Some more info:

- app component has a button which generates 1 notification for each click
- snackbar component displays a notification for 3 seconds then deletes it and switching to the next.
- snackbar container is instantiated with a 0 opacity ()

```
.snackbar {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s linear 2s;
}
```

and there is a `.isVisible` class with opacity one provided on init

```
.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s linear 2s;
}
```

for some reason the snackbar appears right away with max opacity.
Also, i'm not sure how to manage a fade out / fade in between notifications, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `*ngIf` on your snackbar component, that's why css transitions do not work.

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36417931/angular-2-ngif-and-css-transition-animation) in order to use angular BrowserAnimationsModule. There are also options for fade in / out effects when you're animating through BrowserAnimations Module.